# sudo requires root password

Tags: password, sudo, administrator

I've got an admin user `phil` with password `orange`, and the root user is enabled with password `banana`:

- If I type `sudo ls`, and enter the password `orange`, I get `Sorry, try again.`
- If I type `sudo ls`, and enter the password `banana`, it works.

If I disable the root user, sudo doesn't accept either password.

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your user is an admin, they should (by default) be able to use `sudo` (based on the contents of the [sudoers file](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/sudoers.5.html)).

If you re-enable the root user, and examine the contents of the file at `/etc/sudoers`, you should find this line (which specifies that the admin group has the ability to use `sudo`):

```
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

It may be a good idea to confirm that "phil" is in the admin users group. You can perfom this check on the command line using this command (after you've re-enabled root, of course):

```
sudo dseditgroup -o checkmember -m phil admin
```

[It's also possible that the `rootpw` flag may be set in the `/etc/sudoers` file](https://superuser.com/questions/161593/how-do-i-make-sudo-ask-for-the-root-password) (this should be off by default). If you find the following line in that file, see if deleting it will help:

```
Defaults rootpw
```

Comment: "yes phil is a member of admin", and that line is present in `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: @bonh - I've added an additional suggestion to the answer above (`rootpw`)

Comment: that did it!  I found `Defaults rootpw` in `/etc/sudoers` and deleted it, and now I can `sudo` with my user password, as expected.  Thanks!